# Can a subclass type variable refer to a superclass object?

Tags: java, class-hierarchy

In Java's class hierarchy, can an object be initialized in such a manner?

```
subclass object = new superclass();
```

This assumes that both the subclass and superclass have proper constructors, can compile, etc.  Is this type of object construction possible?

Comment: No. Not.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Only the other way around.
When you have an object of a class you can refer to it by a reference of the same class or a parent class and not the reverse. This is probably not related to just Java.
Otherwise it wouldn't make sense. Suppose you have

```
class SuperClass {
    public void method1() {};
}

class SubClass {
    public void method2() {};
}
```

If you do

```
  SubClass object = new SuperClass();
```

and then

```
  object.method2();
```

then theoretically it should compile, because the reference is of type SubClass, but the object is of type SuperClass so it won't have such a method.